# Segue values nil in new ViewController (Xcode 8, Swift 3)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, null, segue

I know this type of question has been posed before. I have read many answers. Most had 0 or 1 votes, and none solved my problem. I am new to coding, so some of the answers were a little beyond me. To keep it short, my values (billAmount) are turning to nil when the segue is performed. The segue works, and print gives the correct value:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let segueController = segue.destination as! ResultsViewController
        segueController.transferBill = "Bill: $\(billAmount)"
    print(billAmount)
}
```

In ResultsViewController, transferBill displays the following:

```
 Bill: $
```

This is expected, except the billAmount does not carry over.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "my values are turning to nil", which values?

Comment: all that i am transferring, including billAmount. i added "(billAmount)" to the question.

Comment: transferBill is this string variable ?

Comment: yes (will show what it displays

Comment: @CJW please show the code for ResultsViewController

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use it as raw billamount value & format it with strings whenever it is required ?